# Removing white font border on a windowless application in C#

Tags: c#, fonts

I know how to draw font on a windowless application in C#, but it has this white border and aliases terribly with backgrounds that aren't white. Does anyone know how to fix this? I have already tried using DrawString and TextRenderer.DrawText. An example image is below.

Looks good here
[image]

Not so good here
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a link to a sample image of what you're talking about?

Comment: If its a label or its a brush or pen, you need to change the Background property to Transparent

Comment: Please give some more details or post a sample code of the text drawn with this border. I've tested drawing text on black background in a WinForms application and it rendered correctly, without the unwanted bright pixels.

Comment: This is the inevitable side-effect of anti-aliasing.  It only works when the background color is correct.  When you rendered the text, the background was white.  Making the text rendering engine draw pixels to blend from red/blue to white. Making those pixels starkly visible when the background isn't white.  The workaround is to give up on anti-aliased rendering.